# How do I only allow pull of certain folders/files in Github?

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a Github repository with multiple folders and files which I use for development and to track changes. I want to share code easily and efficiently with other members at my company by setting them all up on github and encouraging them to pull changes when they've been made.

The only thing is that when they pull, I'd like them to not pull a certain folder within the repository as this folder contains information for individual users.

Does anyone know how to set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't offer this as a capability.  Any person who has read access to a repository can effectively read every object in it, either explicitly, or implicitly.

From the documentation for `gitnamespaces(7)`:

> The fetch and push protocols are not designed to prevent one side from stealing data from the other repository that was not intended to be shared. If you have private data that you need to protect from a malicious peer, your best option is to store it in another repository. This applies to both clients and servers.

So if you want that data stored separately, you'll need to rewrite the history to store that in a separate repository, such as a submodule, and remove it from the original repo.